# Does corruption affect the choices you make?

Tags: warhammer-40k, rogue-trader, corruption

We have begun to take a trip into the mind of our Rogue Trader, and in his self-discovery, he has quite plainly taken the path of Chaos, and is taking corruption points by the handful (took 30 in one session), and any who follow seem to be gaining a few as well.

So how does corruption work in terms of decision making? Do the choices we make become more "corrupted" as we gain more corruption points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there's no mechanics on that, but it's a matter of personal roleplaying. Surely corruption must affect the character, the question is how it should affect.

Some characters would be becoming more and more evil, maybe without noticing it. Others would be somewhat conscious of their corruption, and will try to fight it or at least hide it. The perceptions and judgement can be clouded by corruption, though, so one character may be unaware of how creepy is being from the others.

Apart from that, every 10 points of corruption, the player must roll to avoid manifesting malignancies, which affects the character behaviour and perceptions, like Dark-hearted, which makes you increally cruel and callous. The psychic malignancies should affect decisions, and should be roleplayed too.

Comment: Speaking a bit more specifically; the players pov is that he will do whatever is required to get paid. He'll save a bunch of orphans from a burning orphanage, and then quite happily shove them all back in there, and then level the place with a Macro Cannon. So basically he doesn't have a moral compass. Corruption (should) affect that right?

Comment: @Ben, If you're asking if a high corruption can make the character do something so insane (excuse my poor English), then, yes, it can. But if the character has reached this point, there seems to be no turning back. Those acts will cause more corruption, and the character will fall in a quick spiral toward total corruption, if his Inquisitor or fellows adept don't notice it and kill him in time.

Answer (score 2):

A player who wants to role-play his/her character appropriately must take all things into account, including Corruption or Insanity points. There is no obligation on how you play your character, but by the same token your character's Demeanor also doesn't mandate how you must play your character. One thing the GM can do is award or penalize players with Experience for how they play their character. That way you can nudge them to play lore-friendly, and if they don't then it won't affect them so much that the game changes it just gives them less XP to spend on advancing the character (a character that, if not played true to who it is, than they don't care about the character in the first place).